# How to send/receive original binary Image Data from/to Canvas via WebSockets

Tags: websocket, html5-canvas, webgl

I like to get the binary data from an image. Therefore I need to put it on canvas and retrieve it with the getImageDate method. However, when I compare the size of the source PNG-image with the size of the extracted canvas image, they are different.

```
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    //get image
    var canvasimg = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    alert("binlength: " + canvasimg.data.length);
};

img.src = "images/example.PNG";
```

I've uploaded an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/wLb3q/4/

This behavior is not only with JavaScript but also when I do it via Contextmenu in Firefox (right click on canvas / save image as). The retrieved image is quite a lot smaler then the orignal one.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I can't reproduce this... The PNG size reported by chrome is 1.1KB (roughly 1100 bytes), but your fiddle reports the extracted size as over 12,000 bytes. This makes sense since the PNG is compressed. Are you seeing something different?